# How to handle "multi-variate time-series with multiple observations/individuals" dataset for LSTM Neural Network Pytorch?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, time-series, lstm, forecasting

In the context of multi-variate time-series sequence-to-sequence (e.g., 5 to 1) forecasting with multiple observations/individuals, I am trying to understand how to handle the dataset I have.

The dataset is structured as follow: **20'000** number of observations (e.g., people), **30** features/variables, **70** timestamps (associated with each feature/variable and person). In PyTorch, the dataset shape is (20000, 70, 30) (using dataset_loaded.shape). This means that we have 20'000 people, and for each person, each feature takes 70 values in total (because 70 timestamps).

My goal is to perform binary classification on the people; each person is associated with 30 different time-series (of 70 timestamps) giving information about how to classify the person.

My current issue is to build a correct training dataloader in order to then perform training with mini-batches using a simple LSTM Neural Network.

All the examples I found until now do not have multiple individuals (e.g., people, stocks, devices, etc). It means that there are only "observations" (e.g., for only one particular person or one particular stock or one particular device) made at each time stamp (e.g., they have 70 rows) and for each feature (e.g., they have 30 columns). Consequently, it becomes straightforward to handle such data, use a shifting window and create the correct training data loader since we have a Tensor of size (70, 30).

How should I deal with the "multiple individuals" aspect? Does it mean that I should create 20'000 training dataloaders and train 20'000 LSTM models? It does not seem reasonable...

Does what I am asking even make sense? Is there an obvious way to handle the data better (or at least correctly?) ? Is using only one training dataloader and one LSTM model a reasonable idea for such a task?

I am probably missing something important since I could not seem to find an answer to my questions even though such a task (i.e., having multiple people for which there are multiple features measured at multiple timestamps) should be quite common...

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions. Non-coding questions about ML & data science methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead; please notice the intro and **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info) (applicable also here, despite the lack of the tag).

Comment: Thank you @desertnaut. I am actually looking for an explanation related to the PyTorch design of Tensors, Dataloaders, lstm (in PyTorch), etc, that would allow me to know what would be the right thing(s) to do and how. Thus, code should be discussed despite having to set the context in order to ask the right questions leading to relevant explanations regarding the code.

Comment: @desertnaut
Should I then post my question at Data Science SE even though code is what needs to be discussed?

Comment: Cannot see how code will be discussed (since you don't post any); and I think you have exactly a *methodology* question, and not a programming one. Data Science SE seems like a more appropriate place to ask this.